# calling multiple functions inside one function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new bee to Node. I want to call multiple functions inside a single function in Node and want to merge all the functions result set into single array.

I tried using ".then" and try catch methods but couldn't succeed. Below is my code.

**Router file:**

```
/*jslint node:true*/
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mgrDataCtrl = require('../controllers/mgrDataCtrl');
router.use(session());

// Use body parser to parse JSON body
router.use(bodyParser.json());

// Http Method: GET
router.route('/mgrData').get(mgrDataCtrl.getMgr);
```

**Controller file:**

```
/*jslint node:true*/
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const database = require('../services/database.js');
const mgrapi = require('../services/mgrDataSer.js');


function getMgr(req,res,next){
    const context = {};
    mgrapi.createMgrRec(context).then((resp) => {
        res.status(200).json(resp);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });

    mgrapi.getManagersNames().then((resp1) => {
        res.status(200).json(resp1);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
module.exports.getMgr = getMgr;
```

**Service File:**

Below is my service file calling from controller.

```
const database = require('../services/database.js');

async function createMgrRec(context) {

    let query = 'QUERY ONE';

    //console.log(query);
    const result = await database.simpleExecute(query, binds);
    return result.rows;
}
module.exports.createMgrRec = createMgrRec;


async function getManagersNames() {

    let query = `select firstname, lastname from employees where userid= 123`;

    //console.log(query);
    const result = await database.simpleExecute(query, binds);
    return result.rows;
}
module.exports.getManagersNames = getManagersNames;
```

I am getting the result from 1st function (mgrapi.createMgrRec) in the console. but 2nd function (mgrapi.getManagersNames) is not getting called.

Comment: I think that's because of `mgrapi.createMgrRec(context).then((resp) => {
        res.status(200).json(resp);
    })` - as soon as you get the result from createMgrRec() you return the response to the client, which of course ends the request. You need to wait for both async functions to return, and then combine the results together into a single response to provide to the client

Comment: @ADyson, can you provide me some example for that?

Comment: you'd need to use `Promise.all()` - you can find plenty of examples online

Comment: @sony you combine multiple async functions via [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and then you send response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `createMgrRec` and `getManagersNames` functions both return promises so they run asynchronously.

As soon as one resolves, you are ending the response with `res.status(200).json(...)`.

You could make your `getMgr` function async and then await the 2 promises before responding:

```
async function getMgr(req,res,next) {
  const context = {}

  try {
    const resp1 = await mgrapi.createMgrRec(context)
    const resp2 = await mgrapi.getManagersNames()

    res.status(200).json({ resp1, resp2 })
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'There was an error' })
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.